# European and South American user's browser changes coordinates separator from period to comma in rendered JS

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, localization

App is built and served from US, user in Spain is trying to view a built in gmap on a dashboard to see his locations in the app. The gmap works on all browsers/platforms tested in the US but I am getting word that it doesn't for this and perhaps additional EU and South American users, but only have a handful of examples. I can reproduce at will on this handful of machines I have access to overseas.

The app is written using standard PHP7.x along with various JS libraries including jQuery and the Google GMap suite.

The output from the code ran from the US is:

```
var default_long = '-87.584064762185';
var default_lat = '42.416435054172';
```

Output from EU/SA machines:

```
var default_long = '-87,584064762185';
var default_lat = '42,416435054172';
```

You'll notice that the decimal separator in the EU machine is a comma and the US is a period. This is obviously a localization thing, but I am not sure how or why it is happening.

I am **NOT** changing this programmatically on my side, the function merely pulls the long/lat from the database (which has periods not commas) and dumps out to the web page where it looks to be changed by the user's local machine/browser. I originally had the output without single quotes around the coordinates but added them hoping the browser would treat them as a string and ignore trying to localize them but it didn't work.

So, should I be using some type of Apache or PHP headers to force US localization for numbers or something? The problem I am having has really vague search terms so it has been difficult to find others with the same issue, I appreciate any hel you guys could provide.

Comment: Seeing some code would help. Must be treated as a float, not a string. Echoed with `number_format` or some such?

Comment: @ficiscr the problem was resolved below. Basically, the locale needed to be explicitly stated via PHP using setlocale(). I had no idea rendered code could be affected by locale, just thought values (like form inputs) would be affected. Just to answer your question, the coordinates are stored in the database as doubles and dumped from the db directly to the javascript lat/lon definitions. Possible that I could have used number_format  to force an output using the thousands separator of my choice, but I believe the regional settings on the user machine would have overridden. Oh well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using json_decode at all it can be known to cause this in certain situations.

Set the locale in your script to the following:

`setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US.UTF-8')`

LC_NUMERIC is the important flag to use I think.

[See the PHP documentation for more on this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: More to do with cast to float right? Not really anything specific to `json_decode`?

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I knew it would require forcing the localization of some type, just wasn't able to get my search terms to hone in on that being the specific function needed for this.